# Git Repository based on other repository (Git Alias)

Tags: git

Plesk Git does not allow me to share one git within two subdomains, so I have to use the following setup:

```
Original.git
Alias.git
```

What I need is that Alias.git to be same as Original.git, so when I deploy in Plesk, it will take all changes from Original.git .

Is this possible? Or maybe there is other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to keep two git repos in sync while only updating one of them.

This can be done using git hooks. Have a look [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) for more info. The `update` hook might be best suited for your case.

Comment: How to set up hook to push data to original.git?

Comment: I suppose you'd have to figure out the specifics yourself, but in general you define another `git push` command in the `update` hook. So you need to push your new commits in Original.git to Alias.git. This hook lives in in Original.git and knows the location or address of Alias.git and is permitted to push everything to Alias.git.